# Multiple splitter control

Tags: .net, winforms

In .NET Framework, there is only SplitContainer which contains 2 panels. I need a container which can contain multiple splitters and panels.

See my picture:

[http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/4256/multisplitter.png http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/4256/multisplitter.png](http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/4256/multisplitter.png)

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Why not nest the SplitContainers?

In the left panel of the main splitcontainer, you can add a split panel, and in the right panel you do the same. Then you have four columns (and auto sizing still works)

Comment: But I need a simple thing. Because the number of panels is flexible. I can add a panel or remove a panel when I need. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you also start with one container, and (recursively) keep adding splitcontainers to the right panel. (Panel2), and in the last step just add the control(s) to the right panel.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Splitter control instead of the SplitContainer control. You can stack as many Splitters as you like without extra complications of nesting SplitContainer controls many levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 'lazy' (or find this acceptable), you can simply place 1 & 2 in a splitter, then 3 & 4 in another, then place those 2 splitters in another splitter.